# mkdir and copy files vs volume for webpack in docker

Tags: docker, webpack

I am trying to get webpack setup on my docker container. It is working, and running, but when I save on my local computer it is not updating my files in my container. I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
        container_name: arc-bis-www-web
        restart: on-failure:3
        environment:
          FPM_HOST: 'php'
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        volumes:
          - ./app:/usr/local/src/app
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
        environment:
            CRM_HOST: '192.168.1.79'
            CRM_NAME: 'ARC_test_8_8_17'
            CRM_PORT: '1433'
            CRM_USER: 'sa'
            CRM_PASSWORD: 'Multi*Gr4in'
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/local/src/app
    node:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/node/Dockerfile
        container_name: arc-bis-www-node
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/local/src/app
```

and my node container is run by the following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
RUN useradd --create-home user

RUN mkdir /usr/local/src/app
RUN mkdir /usr/local/src/app/src
RUN mkdir /usr/local/src/app/test
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/app

# Copy application source files
COPY ./app/package.json /usr/local/src/app/package.json
COPY ./app/.babelrc /usr/local/src/app/.babelrc
COPY ./app/webpack.config.js /usr/local/src/app/webpack.config.js
COPY ./app/test /usr/local/src/app/test

RUN chown -R user:user /usr/local/src/app
USER user

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["npm"]
```

Now I have taken out the copy calls from above and it still runs fine, but neither option is allowing me to save files locally and have them show up in the localhost for my container. Ideally, I thought having a volume would allow me to update my local files and have it read by the volume in the container. Does that make sense? I am still feeling my way around Docker. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you start your container with `-v` tag, you can map the container and your local storage. You can find more information [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v-read-only).

Comment: that was not what I was aiming for. I don't want to add tags to the container start, would rather have it called in docker-compose or dockerfile to have my files accessed locally, then I can just startup my container and not have to update any of my local files and not have to remember to add -v everytime I startup.